# Flexbox overflow parent on flex direction column/wrap, with children set to max-width

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a question about *flexbox*.

If I set **flex-direction** to *column* and wrap on parent then set **max-width** on children, they don't shrink on parent shrink but overflow parent. Isn't it some kind of browser bug ?

```
<div class="flex-parent">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>

.flex-parent{
  outline: red 1px solid;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content:space-between;
  & > div{
    outline: blue 1px solid;
    flex-basis: 150px;
    max-width:100px;
    width:100%;
    margin-right: 10px;
    &:last-of-type{
      margin-right:0;
    }
  }
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ELXRRN

Comment: Could you elaborate what you expect to happen compared to what happens instead?

Comment: I would like children to shrink when their parent shrink. 
Children have a set max-width to 100px. When container has not enough free space, children should decrease.

Comment: Why should they shrink? Yes, you set a `max-width` of 100px. But you also set a `width: 100%`, which essentially establishes a `min-width` on the items. They have no reason to shrink below the minimum width of 100% (which is capped at 100px).

Comment: The accepted answer works because the `width` is now 100px (not 100%), and the `max-width` is a flexible 50%.

Comment: this answer works, but i don't agree with 
 you becouse when i set max-width in block layout (
unless it works differently in the flexbox layout)
 i overrides the width of 100% https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QrgoxK,

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/m/max-width/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the initial `width` to `100px` and change the `max-width` to `50%` I think you get the solution you are looking for

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.flex {
  outline: red 1px solid;
  margin: 1em auto width: 50vw;
  width:500px;
  margin:1em auto;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: space-between;
}

.flex.thin {
  width: 150px;
}

.flex>div {
  outline: blue 1px solid;
  flex-basis: 150px;
  width: 100px;
  max-width: 50%;
}

.flex>div:last-of-type {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>

<div class="flex thin">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>
```

[**Codepen Demo**](https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/ELXOvQ)

Comment: thanks it works, but I'm curious why in column direction flexbox does not respect max-width, like in normal box model..

Comment: You previously had the width set to 100% which I suspect was overriding the max-width.

Comment: Normally no but width is kinda different in a flex-column.

Comment: so what is the behavior of width property in the column layout? do u have any article about it?